# How to calculate success probability p

Tags: probability, statistics

> (This can and should be solved without using results about summing geometric series. Use the distribution function $F$.) $Y$ is a geometric random variable with $P(Y \ge 11) = 0.1$, determine the following.
>
> a) The value of the Success probability $p$
>
> b) $P(5 < Y < 15)$

Is this the same as $F(y) = P(Y\le y) = 1-P(Y>y) = 1-(1-p)^y$?

I'm not sure how that formula would apply here, though. Is $p$ $.1$? So, $1-(1-.1)^y$?

What is $y$ supposed to be?

I think for $b$, it should be equal to $F(15) - F(4)$, or $(1-(1-.1)^{15})-(1-(1-.1)^4)$.

Correct?

Comment: Is $\mathbb P(Y=0)>0$?

Comment: In a) you missed the sum: $P(Y\geq 11)=\sum_{y=11}^{\infty} p\cdot (1-p)^{y-1}=0.1$

Comment: Stats is very hard. I have respect for those of you who find it as easy as tying your shoes or basic addition.

Answer (score 1):

At **a)** we have to assume that $P(Y=0)>0$. So the pdf is

$P(Y=k)=(1-p)^k\cdot p$

This is the second version of the geometric distribution. $k$ is the number of failures until the first success. The cdf is

$P(Y\leq n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (1-p)^k\cdot p$

Now it seems that you have to calculate $P(Y\geq 1)$, not $11$ (typo I think). Here you can use the converse probability.

$P(Y\geq 1)=1-P(X=0)=1-(1-p)^0\cdot p=0.1$

Now it is easy to see what $p$ is.

---

At $b)$ you have to sum up all the required probabilities

$P(5<Y<15)=P(6\leq Y\leq 14)=\sum_{k=6}^{14} (1-p)^k\cdot p$